# An unknown error comes with ngrx and angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, angular14

An unknown error is showing with ngrx and angular. When i use store.select of ngrx in my component with state variable. than it is giving an unknown error.

component file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-user',
  templateUrl: './all-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-user.component.css']
})
export class AllUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UsersService,  private readonly store: Store) { }

  users: Users[] = []
  isLoading:boolean = false
  isLoaded: boolean = false
  p: number = 1;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsers()
  }

  getAllUsers(){
    this.store.dispatch(new UserListAction())
    this.userService.getAllUser().subscribe((res:any) => {
     
      this.store.dispatch(new UserListCreatorSuccess(res.users))
    })

    this.store.select(getUserStateUser).subscribe((res:any) => {
      this.users = res.users
    })
     
  }

}
```

Index reducer

```
export interface RootReducerState {
  usersstate: fromUser.userReducerState
}

export const RootReducer: ActionReducerMap<RootReducerState> = {
  usersstate: fromUser.userReducer
};

// get user state
export const getUserState = (state:fromUser.userReducerState) => state
export const getUserStateLoaded = createSelector(getUserState, (state:fromUser.userReducerState) => state.loaded)
export const getUserStateLoading = createSelector(getUserState, (state:fromUser.userReducerState) => state.loading)
export const getUserStateUser = createSelector(getUserState, (state:fromUser.userReducerState) => state.users)


export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<RootReducerState>[] = !environment.production ? [] : [];
```

It is working fine with angular 10 but on working with angular 14. It is giving issue of overload.
Please have a look at the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getUserState selector is not correct. it should be

```
export const getUserState = createFeatureSelector<fromUser.userReducerState>('usersstate')
```